# How can I generate a link to a particular route in Iron?

Tags: rust, iron

There's a table with a list of user on an html page. How can I generate a link to a page where I show an information about a single user?
"/users/:user_name" ?

I can hard-code it, of course. But I want to be safer by generating with help of Iron.

Answer (score 2):

Iron's [router](https://crates.io/crates/router) has two macros that work together.

[`router!`](https://docs.rs/router/0.5.1/router/macro.router.html) allows you to define routes with a key:

```
let router = router!(index: get  "/"       => index,
                     query: get  "/:query" => queryHandler,
                     post:  post "/"       => postHandler);
```

[`url_for!`](https://docs.rs/router/0.5.1/router/macro.url_for.html) allows you to generate a URL for a key:

```
url_for!(request, "foo",
         "query" => "test",
         "extraparam" => "foo")
```